# Unable to turn off/restrict logging for one of the ApacheDS class

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2, apacheds

I am using the following log4j2 configuration to restrict the logging from one of the ApacheDS classes to ERROR and lesser.

```
<logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmIndex">
     <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
</logger>
```

The messages from this particular class are still getting logged at DEBUG level. A similar setting for the following package worked.

```
org.apache.directory.server.core
```

Please help.

Here is the complete configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration name="defaultConfiguration" strict="true" monitorInterval="5">
    <properties>
        <property name="patternlayout">%-5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%4C][%L] - %m%n</property>
        <property name="filename">C:\\Releases\\RCL\\RLKSAdmin\\work\\rcladmin\\logs\\RLKS_ART.log</property>
        <property name="filenamePattern">C:\\Releases\\RCL\\RLKSAdmin\\work\\rcladmin\\logs\\RLKS_ART_%i.log</property>
    </properties>
    <appenders>
        <RollingFile name="ARTFile" fileName="${filename}" filePattern="${filenamePattern}" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${patternlayout}" charset="UTF-8" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="3 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </root>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.core">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.beans">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.context">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.web">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.security">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.ldap">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.jndi">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.validation">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.ui">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.springframework.util">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.schema">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmIndex"/>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmTable"/>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.core">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.core.partition">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.protocol">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
        <logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.shared">
            <appender-ref ref="ARTFile" />
        </logger>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to restrict the log level it may be better not to specify the appender-ref: that way the restriction applies to the root logger and all associated appenders. In the configuration snippet you showed, the restriction only applies to the "ARTFile" appender.

Comment: Remko, can you show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Like this: `<logger level="error" name="org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmIndex"/>`

Comment: I tried what you suggested still no luck. DEBUG messages are getting printed just from this class.

Comment: Can you update the question with your full configuration?

Comment: Remko, please take a look at the complete configuration.

Comment: Can you add `addidivity="false"` to all named logger configs that have an AppenderRef?

Comment: Remko, apart from your suggestions, setting the root logger level to "error" solved the problem. Thanks for the hints.